# Subject specific prediction from heterogenous linear mixed effect model package (lcmm)

Tags: r, prediction, mixed-models

I am fitting a heterogeneous linear mixed effect model which is in the lcmm package in R. Currently, I am only getting the class-specific and weighted subject-specific prediction from the predictY function. But, I want a subject-specific prediction. Is there any way to construct a subject-specific prediction from this package? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: there doesn't seem to be an hlme package.  Are you talking about this? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lcmm/vignettes/latent_class_model_with_hlme.html

Comment: Sorry, It should be lcmm package and your link is the correct one also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. Looks like PredictY gives the mean class-specific predictions and adding them with the multiplication of the random effects from each subject (ranef(model))  and the model design matrix for the random part will provide the subject-specific prediction.